# Programmatically drawing overlaid offset plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 different plots that are currently each saved as separate figures. However, due to space constraints I would like to layer them behind each other and offset like so:

[image: Example image]

I am trying to convey that a similar pattern exists across each plot and this is a nice and compact way of doing so. I would like to programmatically draw such a figure using `matplotlib`, but I'm not sure how to layer and offset the graphs using the usual `pyplot` commands. Any suggestions would be helpful. The following code is a skeleton of what I have currently.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

window = 100
xs = np.arange(100)
ys = np.zeros(100)
ys[80:90] = 1
y2s = np.random.randn(100)/5.0+0.5

with sns.axes_style("ticks"):
    for scenario in ["one", "two", "three"]:
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(xs, ys)
        plt.plot(xs, y2s)
        plt.title(scenario)
        sns.despine(offset=10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually create the axes to plot into and position them as you like.
To highlight this approach modified your example as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

window = 100
xs = np.arange(100)
ys = np.zeros(100)
ys[80:90] = 1
y2s = np.random.randn(100)/5.0+0.5

fig = plt.figure()
with sns.axes_style("ticks"):
    for idx,scenario in enumerate(["one", "two", "three"]):
        off = idx/10.+0.1
        ax=fig.add_axes([off,off,0.65,0.65], axisbg='None')
        ax.plot(xs, ys)
        ax.plot(xs, y2s)
        ax.set_title(scenario)
        sns.despine(offset=10)
```

which gives a plot like
[image]

Here, I used `fig.add_axes` to add manually created axes objects to the predefined figure object. The arguments specify the position and size of the newly created axes, see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes).
Note that I also set the axes background to be transparent (`axisbg='None'`).

Comment: Thanks! My example figure was terrible for this, but your method works well.